# Android- SQLite created and never closed

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a problem. I Worked with one table in my database and I had no problem...

Well now I add another table and problems started..

In my principal activity, I open the database (writable mode) to fill information stored in an array.. then I close it, after that I reopen it (readable mode) and I fill a table with data stored in my database... then I close DB.   that was working in all the activities I was doing that..

Well now I have another activity that just do the same with another table,  open it as writable to fill it, close..  and then open it as readable and fill a table and close..

And after I do this, I have the LogCat that says SQLite created and never closed..    what? I did the same thing as always..   here is part of my activity which is getting me into trouble:

```
     UsuariosSQLiteHelper usdbh =
                new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(this, "DBIncidentes", null, 1);

            SQLiteDatabase db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();         //Abro base de datos para escritura

            if(db != null)
            {

                 db.execSQL("DELETE from Moviles");
                 for (int i=0; i<= (vecTotal.length) -1; i++) {



                String reg = vecTotal[i].toString(); 
                String [] inc = TextUtils.split(reg, "\\^");




                String numMovil = inc[0];
                String colMovil = inc[1];
                String estado = inc[2];
                String localidad = inc[3];
                String strCantServ = inc[4];

                Integer cantServ = Integer.parseInt(strCantServ);



                try{                

                    //Insertamos los datos en la tabla Incidentes
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Moviles ( idInterno, numMovil, colMovil, estado, localidad, cantServ) " +
             "VALUES ("+(i+1)+", '" + numMovil +"', '" + colMovil +"' , '" + estado +"', '" + localidad +"', " +cantServ +" )");



}

catch (Exception e)

{
    e.getMessage();


}






                 }



                 db.close();


            }




            UsuariosSQLiteHelper bdLlena =
                    new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(this, "DBIncidentes", null, 1);

                SQLiteDatabase db2 = bdLlena.getReadableDatabase();



            if(db2 != null)


            {






           String query = "Select * FROM Moviles";



           Cursor d = db2.rawQuery(query,null);

            if (d.moveToFirst())

                do {


                Integer j = 1;

                    Integer idInterno = d.getInt(0);
                    String numMovil = d.getString(1);
                    String colMovil = d.getString(2);
                    String estado = d.getString(3);
                    String localidad = d.getString(4);
                    Integer cantServ = d.getInt(5);



                     TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

                        tr.setId(idInterno);
                        tr.setOnClickListener(this);
                        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   


                          //------------------------------------------------- 

                        //seteo el campo Numero de Movil

                           TextView cmpNumMovil = new TextView(this);
                           cmpNumMovil.setId(200+j);

                           int colorInt = Color.parseColor(colMovil);
                           cmpNumMovil.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                           cmpNumMovil.setText(numMovil);

                           cmpNumMovil.setBackgroundColor(colorInt);
                           cmpNumMovil.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                           cmpNumMovil.setWidth(10);
                           View v = new View(this);
                           v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
                           tl.addView(v);
                           tr.addView(cmpNumMovil);

                         //----------------------------------------------------------------  
                         //seteo el campo entidad

                           TextView cmpEstado = new TextView(this);
                           cmpEstado.setId(300+j);
                           cmpEstado.setText(estado);
                           cmpEstado.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                           cmpEstado.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
                           tr.addView(cmpEstado);

                           //----------------------------------------------------------------  


                           TextView cmpLoc = new TextView(this);
                           cmpLoc.setId(300+j);
                           cmpLoc.setText(localidad);
                           cmpLoc.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                           cmpLoc.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
                           tr.addView(cmpLoc);



                        //----------------------------------------------------------------  


                           TextView cmpCantServ = new TextView(this);
                           cmpCantServ.setId(300+j);
                           cmpCantServ.setText(cantServ);
                           cmpCantServ.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                           cmpCantServ.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
                           tr.addView(cmpCantServ);





            j++;


                 } while(d.moveToNext());



            }



            db2.close();





    }


    catch (Exception e)

    {


        e.getMessage();
    }





}
```

I use the same helper for the two tables, and my new table is full of data.. but it isn't displayed in my screen and i have the error of created and never closed..

Answer (score 0):

In `UsuariosSQLiteHelper` class, did you really implement method `close()`?

Comment: not really, but i thought db.close(); is a method of the api, just close my bd..  and i used it with just 1 table and i had no problems, thats rare

Answer (score 0):

try to implement the overridden method close() for database, and after every operation call
close(), will cloase ur database...

```
@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}
```

Hope u get my point...